# BSImagePicker all Images blurred

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using BSImagePicker instead of UIImagePicker to enable multi select.
I'm using following code for this:

```
    let bsImagePicker = BSImagePickerViewController()
    bsImagePicker.maxNumberOfSelections = 4

    self.bs_presentImagePickerController(bsImagePicker, animated: true, select: { (asset : PHAsset) in

    }, deselect: { (asset : PHAsset) in

    }, cancel: { (assets : [PHAsset]) in

    }, finish: { (assets : [PHAsset]) in

        for asset in assets {

            self.selectedAssets.append(asset)

            self.convertAssetsToImage()
        }

    }, completion: nil)
```

And for converting the PHAsset to an image I'm using this code:

```
func convertAssetsToImage() {

    for asset in selectedAssets {

        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        var thumbnail = UIImage()
        option.isSynchronous = true

        manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 340, height: 365), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: {(result, info) -> Void in

            thumbnail = result!
        })

        self.selectedPhotos.append(thumbnail)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.imageViewImage.animationImages = self.selectedPhotos
        self.imageViewImage.animationDuration = 5.0
        self.imageViewImage.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

But all images are blurred. If the ImagePicker is shown, all images are slightly blurred and after selection the image is still blurred.

Thats an image of selection Screen:

[image: Selection Screen]

Thats an Image of the selected Image:

[image: Blurred Image]

And for example, this is an image if I'm using an UIImagePicker:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add these two `PHImageRequestOptions` to tell photos to provide a high-quality image (possibly sacrificing speed).

```
option.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
option.resizeMode = .exact
```

Comment: Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

**100% worked for me :)**

```
                   let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
                    option.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
                    option.resizeMode = .exact

                    PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option) { (image, info) in
                        // Do something with image
                       
                    }
```